# Asking about date

Tags: british-english, time

I'd like to know which way of asking questions is more common in the UK. Is there any difference?

> 1 What is the date today or What date is today?
>   2 What is the day today or What day is today?
>   3 What time is it or What is the time?
>   4 Whose bag is it or Whose is the bag?
>   5 What season is now or What is the season now?
>   6 What is the weather like today or How is the weather?

Thank you.

Comment: Three of your examples are not idiomatic, and require an _it_: "What date is it today?", "What day is it today" and "What season is it today". With that change, they are all idiomatic, and any judgments I would make between them are very slight.

Comment: Thanks. I actually understand the difference between dates and days. What I meant is - how to ask it properly, in the right way. The same is for other 4 questions written above.

Comment: I didn't talk about the difference between dates and days. My answer is that, once you fix up the three instances of _is now_ or _is today_ by inserting _it_, there is almost nothing to choose between your pairs of questions.

Comment: Hm, there was another comment before yours one minute ago, sorry.

Comment: @Colin I find nothing unidiomatic about “What day/date is today?”. In fact, I find it _less_ idiomatic if you add in the dummy _it_, though only marginally. No, scratch that: not less idiomatic—less mellifluous. (This does not go for “What season is it now?”.)

Comment: Anna - this shows that views of what is idiomatic are to some degree subjective. Janus prefers _what day is today_, I prefer _what day is it today_.